# Performing operation based on Boolean logic on a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, series

I'm trying to solve a problem. I have a pandas series:

```
  delta
id     len
0      122
1       88
2       86
3      202
4       87
5      117
6      170
7      163
8       68
9       17
10      99
11     132
12      42
13      34
14      53
15      69
16      32
17      39
18      30
19      51
20       7
21      40
22       6
23      18
25      92
27       3
28       5
29       6
31      23
32      25
33      23
34      21
35      13
36      30
37      16
38      19
40      38
43       7
44       5
45      10
46       9
49       4
50      17
51      18
53       3
56       9
57      28
72       8
76      17
84       5
95      20
113     14
131     26
150      7
180     27
Name: delta, dtype: int64
```

what I'm basically trying to do is this:

sum of len values for ids equal to 0
sum of len values for ids equal to 0 or 1
sum of len values for ids equal to 0 or 1 or 2 and so on.

My problem is that I can get a sum of lens for each id. Like 0 = 122, 1 = 210 etc. But I can't figure out a way to apply the OR operation to ids. The part I can't come up with a solution for is equal to x or y, and increase that incrementally in the range of ids.

I really appreciate your help or any tips and suggestion you might have!

Comment: Do you need `df['len'].cumsum()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your ids are sorted, then compute the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
out = df.set_index('id').sort_index().cumsum()
```

Or:

```
out = df.sort_values(by='id').assign(len=lambda d: d['len'].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
     id   len
0     0   122
1     1   210
2     2   296
3     3   498
4     4   585
5     5   702
6     6   872
7     7  1035
8     8  1103
...
51  113  2260
52  131  2286
53  150  2293
54  180  2320
```